# arch linux - Pulse audio plays too fast

Tags: audio, arch-linux, pulse-audio, performance

i have a problem that all my audio playback is too fast. I have found this: [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=36795) but i dont know where to disable the multirate locking and decreas the multitrack internal clock samplerate to 48000

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so when one hase Arch Linux, then he must read only the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/). I have found why is PulseAudio so fast: [Glitches, skips or crackling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling)

**Glitches, skips or crackling**

The newer implementation of PulseAudio sound server uses a timer-based audio scheduling instead of the traditional interrupt-driven approach.

Timer-based scheduling may expose issues in some ALSA drivers. On the other hand, other drivers might be glitchy without it on, so check to see what works on your system.

To turn timer-based scheduling off add `tsched=0` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Then restart the PulseAudio server:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```

Do the reverse to enable timer-based scheduling, if not already enabled by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, that section no longer exists on the Wiki.  Do you know where the documentation might be right now, or would you mind providing additional information to help others out?

Comment: wikis have history :) https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=PulseAudio&oldid=281713#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling but I don't know it it helps now. If someone has deleted the section, it must have a reason

Comment: I'm asking you, as the answer provider, to look this information up and provide it HERE, on this site.  Otherwise, I'm going to downvote your answer.

Comment: To anyone still having trouble with this, the section was moved to PulseAudio/Troubleshooting: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling